# Android SQLITE query exception error?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add sqlite in my application i have created DB and table but the SELECT and INSERT query is not working i Don't know why?
Here i have added my code:

```
static  Cursor c;
SQLiteDatabase db;

db=openOrCreateDatabase("weatherregisterDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weatherRegister(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR,username VARCHAR,password VARCHAR,confirmpassword VARCHAR);");


        register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO weatherRegister(id,name,username,password,confirmpassword) VALUES('',sample,sample,sample,sample);");

                c=db.rawQuery("SELECT  username FROM weatherRegister WHERE username=sample", null);
```

My Error is:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: sample (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO weatherRegister(id,name,username,password,confirmpassword) VALUES('',sample,sample,sample,sample);
```

Comment: show your logcat too

Comment: Is `CREATE TABLE` query is working? probably not because *missing space between column name and type* please share crash log

Comment: Your query is wrong.There is no column named sample in your table...Try to pass the username different.

Comment: `id` is an integer and `AUTOINCREMENT` so you don't need set that value , even you want ,`''` is not right, remove `id` key  and values from insert statement. try use `ContentValues` for inserting instead of sql query

Comment: Use this link for help  - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Answer (score 2):

could you provide the error ?

but at first look this line

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO weatherRegister(id,name,username,password,confirmpassword) VALUES('',sample,sample,sample,sample);");
```

should be :

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO weatherRegister(id,name,username,password,confirmpassword) VALUES('sample','sample','sample','sample');");
```

you don't have to wire ('') for (id) if it's auto increment , also (String) values should be between ('')

and the same for the select query

Original :

```
SELECT  username FROM weatherRegister WHERE username=sample
```

Update to :

```
SELECT  username FROM weatherRegister WHERE username='sample'
```

hope that will help before you show us the error.

Comment: Now Error came like that::Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad Okaily's answer is correct. One more thing is you don't need to write _id in your insert statement since it's auto-increment. 
I've tried it in SQLite command line and seems it's working fine.
Can't give you an Android code version because my PC in company is too slow for eclipse or android studio.

`SQLite version 3.8.7.4 2014-12-09 01:34:36
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> INSERT INTO weatherRegister(id,name,username,password,confirmpassword) VALUES('sample','sample','sample','sample');
Error: 4 values for 5 columns
sqlite> INSERT INTO weatherRegister(name,username,password,confirmpassword) VALUES('sample','sample','sample','sample');
sqlite> select * from weatherRegister;
1|sample|sample|sample|sample
sqlite>`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
c=db.rawQuery("SELECT  username FROM weatherRegister WHERE username=sample", null);
```

to

```
 c=db.rawQuery("SELECT  username FROM weatherRegister WHERE username='sample'", null);
```

Please note single inverted comma near "sample".Hope it will help.Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the VARCHAR data type use TEXT as the datatype for your attributes.